# .GetAbsolutePathName(".") in vbscript does not get correct path when run by task scheduler

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to run a vb script using task scheduler.
I am using the .GetAbsolutePathName(".") to get the full path of the script. 
When I run the script manually, it was able to get the correct path. But when run as scheduled task, it outputs "C:\Windows\System32\ as the path.

I am using the path name to get the full path of an Excel file that I would like to run. The excel file is saved within the same path as the script.

Below is my code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

scurDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

set fso = nothing

Set myxlApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

wscript.echo scurDir & "\OOO Automation Tool.xlsm"

Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open( scurDir & "\OOO Automation Tool.xlsm" )

myxlApplication.Visible = False

myxlApplication.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

'Run routine
myWorkBook.Application.Run "MOutofOffice.pDetectIdleTime" 

'Close application
myxlApplication.Quit

'Release objects
set myxlApplication = nothing
set myWorkBook = nothing
```

Can you help me get the correct path?

Comment: Where is your script located, and what path do you expect?

Comment: It is located on \10.163.13.11\IBPOv2$\BEF_Manila\QUALITY\Team Members\Me\Projects, and I expect to get that path using the fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with

```
With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    WScript.Echo .GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder.Path
End With
```

You need the path where the script is stored, not the current active directory, what you retrieve with the `"."` reference.

Comment: Thanks MC ND! Worked perfectly fine!